# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

На сервере есть модуль, отвечающий за валидацию:

```js
const handlers = {
    isExists() {
        return function(user, res) {
            if (!user) {
                return res.status(200).json({
                    msg: "Такого пользователя не существует"
                });
            }
        };
    }
}

module.exports = handlers;
```

При попытке вызвать `.isExists()`, возвращается ошибка от node.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const handlers = require('../modules/handlers');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/edit',
    async(req, res) => {
        try {
            const isExists = handlers.isExists();
            isExists(null, res)
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                msg: config.get("500err"),
                err: err.stack
            })
        }
    }
);
```

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: а `return isExists(null, res)`

Comment: @nörbörnën, мне не нужно `return`. `.isExists()` - промежуточный обработчик.

Comment: твой "промежуточный" обработчик не промежуточный - он выставил status ответа и сформировал body ответа. что же тут промежуточного?

Comment: @nörbörnën, но если я передаю ему не null, то он не выставляет статус и ответ, программа идёт дальше

Comment: а если передаёшь нечто то он отправляет ответ в который ты потом лезешь с попыткой изменить заголовки. это всё потому что у тебя структура приложения не правильная. с req/res должен работать контроллер, а "промежуточные обработчики" должны принимать некие данные и на основании этих данных выполнять действия, принимать решения. т.е. твой isExists должен получить req.body и вернуть исключение, а в контроллере ты должен это исключение поймать и вернуть какой-то статус запроса

Comment: @nörbörnën, понятно, но тогда получается, что код дублируется. Как можно этого избежать?

Comment: какой код дублируется?

Comment: @nörbörnën, почти в каждом контроллере вызывается if (!user) {} и тп

Comment: @nörbörnën, хотелось бы вынести код обработчиков в отдельную компоненту

Comment: для этого нужно написать мидварь и повесить её на роут

Comment: выше я писал про авторизационную мидлварь. она должна существовать в твоём проекте (passport или что-то ещё). но для расширения кругозора прочитай https://express-validator.github.io/docs/

Comment: @nörbörnën, express-validator кнш хорошо, но он не сообщает, что именно вызвало ошибку. Поэтому я и решил сделать свой валидатор

Comment: ты ошибаешься, он может сообщить https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-error-messages.html#custom-validator-level. но у тебя должна быть миддлварь авторизационного, а не валидационного типа